# cf ic plugin not able to find docker daemon while authentication

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

When I use cf ic plugin on command prompt, it gives me the following message:

> Checking local Docker configuration... Your system was authenticated
>   with the IBM Containers API, however the local Docker daemon is not
>   reachable to authenticate it with the IBM Containers registry. You can
>   still run IBM Containers on the cloud but will not be able to push or
>   pull images.

Not sure why this is happening because docker is running fine for me on my local windows PC. When I try the docker-machine env at my command prompt, I get the following output:

```
"SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1"
"SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
"SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.docker\machine\machines  \default"
"SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default"
 REM Run this command to configure your shell:
"REM     FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO %i"
```

Any hints on what could be wrong? I searched in communities but can't find much.

Answer (score 0):

It was a miss from my side.

Given that I downloaded docker for windows, it was running inside the VirtualBox. So, tried cf ic login from Mingw console instead of windows command prompt and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From a regular CMD sheel, this would have worked:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env') DO %i"
```

Then you could type docker command against the docker-machine '`default`'

The other option is to open an interactive shell on the '`default`' VM.

```
docker-machine ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

To use cf ic bluemix for docker containers there are three requirements
- have cf Bluemix command line tool available
- have a local docker environment working and started on the same system of your cf
- have the cf docker containers plugin installed